# List of TextFields clearing when they're updated - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I am creating a simple grocery list creator in Flutter. I am trying to go about this by having a plus button that will add ingredient text fields when you press it. Here is what I have done:

```
body: Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 30.0),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
              'Ingredients                                                                     ',
              style: GoogleFonts.biryani(fontSize: 15.0)),
          IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                countings++;
              });
              debugPrint('$countings');
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
      ListOfIngsWidget(countings, key: UniqueKey())
    ],
  ),
)
```

And here is the ListOfIngsWidget:

```
class ListOfIngsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int countIngs;

  const ListOfIngsWidget(this.countIngs, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListOfIngsState createState() => _ListOfIngsState();
}

class _ListOfIngsState extends State<ListOfIngsWidget> {
  List<TextEditingController> _controllerList = [];
  List<TextEditingController> _numControllerList = [];
  List<Widget> _ingList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= widget.countIngs; i++) {
      TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
      TextField textField = TextField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Ingredient $i',
        ),
      );
      TextEditingController numcontroller = TextEditingController();
      TextField numField = TextField(
        controller: numcontroller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: '#', labelText: '#'),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      );
      _ingList.add(Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 250,
                child: textField,
              )),
          Text('x', style: GoogleFonts.biryani(fontSize: 15)),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 75,
                child: numField,
              ))
        ],
      ));
      _controllerList.add(controller);
      _numControllerList.add(numcontroller);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: Flexible(
        child: ListView(children: _ingList),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The only problem is that if you press the plus button after you have already entered values into one of the textFields, it will clear the field. I kind of understand why this is happening, but is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Hi! I didn't look fully at your code but what first caught my attention is that you are using a `UniqueKey` as your key. This means every time that outer widget rebuilds , your whole list will be rebuilt and its state will be lost. Keys should be unique and specific to items and are for the children of lists not really the lists themselves

Comment: Hi! I'm pretty new to Flutter, so I don't fully understand how keys work, but I found this solution on another thread because setState() wasn't working for the void function. Can you please describe what I should do?

Comment: I think it's because you create your list of controllers in initState which only builds once (unless you change the parent's key, forcing a complete rebuild). Instead, you might achieve what you want by moving the list of controllers up to the parent so the `setState` instead adds/removes the controllers themselves. You can then pass down the controllers to ListOfIngsWidgets and have it be stateless too.

Comment: There's another option of using the `didUpdateWidget` lifecycle instead but I think that might not be as clean and is more declarative than functional

Comment: I still don't fully understand, could you please link a tutorial or something of how to pass objects between classes?

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing some proper disposal of textControllers but here's the gist. As for further reading into keys and why they're necessary, I'd read this [medium post](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d)

```dart
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  final _controllerList = <TextEditingController>[];
  final _numControllerList = <TextEditingController>[];

  /*
    If the user had previous ingredients (say from a db), then you
    would fill _controllerList and _numControllerList here using
    the old ingredients to populate.

    @override
    void initState() {

      for (ingredient in previousIngredients) {
        final controller = TextEditingController(text: ingredient.text);
        final numController = TextEditingController();

        _controllerList.add(controller);
        _numControllerList.add(numController);
      }

      super.initState();
    }
  */

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 30.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Ingredients'),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _controllerList.add(TextEditingController());
                      _numControllerList.add(TextEditingController());
                    });
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_controllerList.isEmpty) return;
                    setState(() {
                      _controllerList.removeLast();
                      _numControllerList.removeLast();
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            ListOfIngsWidget(_controllerList, _numControllerList),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListOfIngsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ListOfIngsWidget(this.controllerList, this.numControllerList)
      : assert(controllerList.length == numControllerList.length);

  final List<TextEditingController> controllerList;
  final List<TextEditingController> numControllerList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _ingList = <Widget>[];

    for (var i = 0; i < controllerList.length; i++) {
      final textField = TextField(
        controller: controllerList[i],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Ingredient $i',
        ),
      );
      final numField = TextField(
        controller: numControllerList[i],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: '#', labelText: '#'),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      );

      _ingList.add(
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 250,
                  child: textField,
                )),
            Text('x', style: GoogleFonts.biryani(fontSize: 15)),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 75,
                child: numField,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return Container(
      child: Flexible(
        child: ListView(children: _ingList),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "If the user had previous ingredients (say from a db)" What is a db?

Comment: Also, your code is giving me an error:"RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: -1"

Comment: db - Database. The range error happens because you likely removed from an empty list. I did not test the code so it was meant more as a guide. To avoid that case though inside the `onPressed` for the remove button, you'd first check if `_controllerList.isEmpty()` first and if it is just return.